# javascript weird console logs

Tags: javascript

I've got a assignment to make function that gives you a sorted array with 6 random numbers from 1 to 45. None of the array values should equal to one another.

I thought about a solution that would work in Java but the JavaScript console logs I get are pretty confusing. Could anyone help me out?

```
"use strict";

var numbers = [];
for(var x = 1; x <46;x++){
    numbers.push(x);
}


function LottoTipp(){
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <6; i++){
      var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()* 45);
      var pushed = numbers[randomNum];
      result.push(pushed);
      numbers.splice(randomNum)
    }

    return console.log(result) + console.log(numbers);

}

LottoTipp();
```

the console logs

```
[ 34, 7, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: You don't use `splice`correctly

Comment: Also, since you added it back, how is Java relevant?

Comment: your `splice` is messed up, it should be `splice(index, number of delete items)`

Comment: just add `splice(randomNum, 1)` and it outputs (6) [33, 7, 25, 24, 26, 28]
(39) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]

Comment: still, your logic isnt right since random numbers could eventually produce the same arrays. also, splice modifies the original array, so you need to make a copy before you start splicing it.

Comment: @joe thanks! Also as the numbers array lenght gets smaller the randomNum could be longer than the numbers array. so my solution would be instead of the *45 -> numbers.lenght() but now the console says TypeError: numbers.lenght is not a function

Comment: It has to be `length` not `lenght`.

Comment: @Adder well its a typo in the comment its right in the code though. same error

Comment: Well `length` is not a function but a field, remove the `()` after it.

Comment: @Adder thank you, i make stupid mistakes all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There were three problems:
>
> - If you want to remove one item of an array you have to [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it by the items [**index**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and give a deletecount.
>
>   In your case: `numbers.splice(randomNum, 1);`
> - You have to use [**`Math.floor`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) instead of [**`Math.round`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), because `Math.floor` always down to the nearest integerer, while `Math.round` searches for the nearest integer wich could be higher than `numbers.length`.
> - After removing one item the `length` of the array has been changed. So you have to multiply by `numbers.lenght` instead of 45.
>
>   In your case: `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()* numbers.length);`

```js
"use strict";

var numbers = [];
for(var x = 1; x < 46; x++){
    numbers.push(x);
}


function LottoTipp(){
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()* numbers.length);
      var pushed = numbers[randomNum];
      result.push(pushed);
      numbers.splice(randomNum, 1);
    }

    return console.log(result) + console.log(numbers);

}

LottoTipp();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()* numbers.length);`

Comment: thanks a lot !well i did that but now the console shows TypeError: numbers.lenght is not a function

Comment: thats because it has to be `length` and not `lenght` :)

Comment: I have to insist that `Math.floor` is correct. `math.round` leads to `undefined` entry, if you click "Run Code Snippet" often enough.

Comment: got one more point only for your information: you dont need to use `.indexOf` in this case, since `randomNum` is already the index of the number you've pushed. My Fault, updated again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want an array with random unique numbers I would suggest doing it like this:

```
<script>
     var array = [];
     for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var number = Math.round(Math.random() *45);
        if(array.indexOf(number) == -1) { //if number is not already inside the array
            array.push(number);
        } else { //if number is inside the array, put back the counter by one
            i--;
        }
     }
     console.log(array);
</script>
```

Comment: While this could be a nice solution, the OP will not get whats going wrong with its own code. So there will be no learning effect.

Comment: @J.Sadi is right but i appreciate the help and perspective on another way to do this assignment. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the console statement the issue is that you are modifying the numbers array in your for loop. As you are picking the random number between 1-45 in this statement:-

```
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()* 45);
```

and you expect that value would be present in the numbers array at that random index. However you are using array.splice() and providing only first parameter to the function. The first parameter is the start index from which you want to start deleting elements, find syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). This results in deleting all the next values in the array.Therefore if you pick a random number number say.. 40, value at `numbers[40]` is undefined as you have deleted contents of the array.
[image]

if you want to generate unique set of numbers follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378870/generating-unique-random-numbers-integers-between-0-and-x/8378910).

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the number in the result if it is unique otherwise take out a new number and then sort it. Here is an implementation:

```
let result = []
while(result.length < 6) {
    let num = Math.round(Math.random() * 45);
    if(!result.includes(num)) {
        result.push(num);
    }
}
result.sort((a,b) => {
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While it may answer the question, try your best to not just paste code, but give explanation along.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!