# Performance of assigning values to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

Code optimizing is said here in SO that profiling is the first step for optimizing javascript and the suggested engines are profilers of Chrome and Firefox. The problem with those is that they tell in some weird way the time that each function is executed, but I haven't got any good understanding of them. The most helpful way would be that the profiler would tell, how many times each row is executed and if ever possible also the time that is spent on each row. This way would it be possible to see the bottlenecks strictly. But before such tool is implemented/found, we have two options:

1) make own calculator which counts both the time and how many times certain code block or row is executed
2) learn to understand which are slow methods and which are not

For option 2 [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com) is of great help. I have tried to learn optimizing arrays and made a speed test in [JSPERF.COM](http://jsperf.com/pre-filled-array). The following image shows the results in 5 main browsers and found some bottlenecks that I didn't know earlier.

[image: Speed test]

**The main findings were:**

1) Assigning values to arrays is significantly slower than assigning to normal variables despite of which method is used for assigning.

2) Preinitializing and/or prefilling array before performance critical loops can improve speed significantly

3) Math trigonometric functions are not so slow when compared to pushing values into arrays(!)

Here are the explanations of every test:

---

**1. non_array (100%):**

The variables were given a predefined value this way:

```
var non_array_0=0;
var non_array_1=0;
var non_array_2=0;
...
```

and in timed region they were called this way:

```
non_array_0=0;
non_array_1=1;
non_array_2=2;
non_array_3=3;
non_array_4=4;
non_array_5=5;
non_array_6=6;
non_array_7=7;
non_array_8=8;
non_array_9=9;
```

The above is an array-like variable, but there seems to be no way to iterate or refer to those variables in other way as oppocite to array. Or is there?

**Nothing in this test is faster than assigning a number to variable.**

---

**2. non_array_non_pre (83.78%)**

Exactly the same as test 1, but the variables were not pre-initialized nor prefilled. The speed is 83,78% of the speed of test 1. In every tested browser the speed of prefilled variables was faster than non-prefilled. **So initialize (and possibly prefill) variables outside any speed critical loops.**

The test code is here:

```
var non_array_non_pre_0=0;
var non_array_non_pre_1=0;
var non_array_non_pre_2=0;
var non_array_non_pre_3=0;
var non_array_non_pre_4=0;
var non_array_non_pre_5=0;
var non_array_non_pre_6=0;
var non_array_non_pre_7=0;
var non_array_non_pre_8=0;
var non_array_non_pre_9=0;
```

---

**3. pre_filled_array (19.96 %):**

**Arrays are evil!** When we throw away normal variables (test1 and test2) and take arrays in to the picture, the speed decreases significantly. **Although we make all optimizations (preinitialize and prefill arrays) and then assign values directly without looping or pushing, the speed decreases to 19.96 percent.** This is very sad and I really don't understand why this occurs. This was  one of the main shocks to me in this test. Arrays are so important, and I have not find a way to make many things without arrays.

The test data is here:

```
pre_filled_array[0]=0;
pre_filled_array[1]=1;
pre_filled_array[2]=2;
pre_filled_array[3]=3;
pre_filled_array[4]=4;
pre_filled_array[5]=5;
pre_filled_array[6]=6;
pre_filled_array[7]=7;
pre_filled_array[8]=8;
pre_filled_array[9]=9;
```

---

**4. non_pre_filled_array (8.34%):**

This is the same test as 3, but  the array members are not preinitialized nor prefilled, only optimization was to initialize the array beforehand: `var non_pre_filled_array=[];`

The speed decreases 58,23 % compared to preinitilized test 3. **So preinitializing and/or prefilling array over doubles the speed.**

The test code is here:

```
non_pre_filled_array[0]=0;
non_pre_filled_array[1]=1;
non_pre_filled_array[2]=2;
non_pre_filled_array[3]=3;
non_pre_filled_array[4]=4;
non_pre_filled_array[5]=5;
non_pre_filled_array[6]=6;
non_pre_filled_array[7]=7;
non_pre_filled_array[8]=8;
non_pre_filled_array[9]=9;
```

---

**5. pre_filled_array[i] (7.10%):**

Then to the loops. Fastest looping method in this test. The array was preinitialized and prefilled.

The speed drop compared to inline version (test 3) is 64,44 %. This is so remarkable difference that I would say, do not loop if not needed. If array size is small (don't know how small, it have to be tested separately), using inline assignments instead of looping are wiser.

And because the speed drop is so huge and we really need loops, it's is wise to find [better looping method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592908/1691517) (eg. `while(i--)`).

The test code is here:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  pre_filled_array[i]=i;
}
```

---

**6. non_pre_filled_array[i] (5.26%):**

If we do not preinitialize and prefill array, the speed decreases 25,96 %. Again, preinitializing and/or prefilling before speed critical loops is wise.

The code is here:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
  non_pre_filled_array[i]=i;
}
```

---

**7. Math calculations (1.17%):**

Every test have to be some reference point. Mathematical functions are considered slow. The test consisted of ten "heavy" Math calculations, but now comes the other thing that struck me in this test. Look at speed of 8 and 9 where we push ten integer numbers to array in loop. Calculating these 10 Math functions is more than 30% faster than pushing ten integers into array in loop. So, may be it's easier to convert some array pushes to preinitialized non-arrays and keep those trigonometrics. Of course if there are hundred or thousands of calculations per frame, it's wise to use eg. sqrt instead of sin/cos/tan and use taxicab distances for distance comparisons and [diamond angles (t-radians) for angle comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675998), but still the main bottleneck can be elsewhere: looping is slower than inlining, pushing is slower than using direct assignment with preinitilization and/or prefilling, code logic, drawing algorithms and DOM access can be slow. All cannot be optimized in Javascript (we have to see something on the screen!) but all easy and significant we can do, is wise to do. Someone here in SO has said that code is for humans and readable code is more essential than fast code, because maintenance cost is the biggest cost. This is economical viewpoint, but I have found that code optimizing can get the both: elegance and readability and the performance. And if 5% performance boost is achieved and the code is more straightforwad, it gives a good feeling!

The code is here:

```
non_array_0=Math.sqrt(10435.4557);
non_array_1=Math.atan2(12345,24869);
non_array_2=Math.sin(35.345262356547);
non_array_3=Math.cos(232.43575432);
non_array_4=Math.tan(325);
non_array_5=Math.asin(3459.35498534536);
non_array_6=Math.acos(3452.35);
non_array_7=Math.atan(34.346);
non_array_8=Math.pow(234,222);
non_array_9=9374.34524/342734.255;
```

---

**8. pre_filled_array.push(i) (0.8%):**

**Push is evil!** Push combined to loop is baleful evil! This is for some reason very slow method to assign values into array. Test 5 (direct assignments in loop), is nearly 9 times faster than this method and both methods does exactly the same thing: assign integer 0-9 into preinitialized and prefilled array. I have not tested if this push-for-loop evilness is due to pushing or looping or the combination of both or the looping count. There are in JSPERF.COM other examples that gives  conflicting results. It's wiser to test just with the actual data and make decisions. This test may not be compatible with other data than what was used.

And here is the code:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  pre_filled_array.push(i);
}
```

---

**9. non_pre_filled_array.push(i) (0.74%):**

The last and slowest method in this test is the same as test 8, but the array is not prefilled. A little slower than 9, but the difference is not significant (7.23%). But let's take an example and compare this slowest method to  the fastest. **The speed of this method is 0.74% of the speed of the method 1, which means that method 1 is 135 times faster than this.** So think carefully, if arrays are at all needed in particular use case. If it is only one or few pushes, the total speed difference is not noticeable, but on the other hand if there are only few pushes, they are very simple and  elegant to convert to non-array variables.

This is the code:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  non_pre_filled_array.push(i);
}
```

---

And finally the obligatory SO question:

**Because the speed difference according to this test seems to be so huge between non-array-variable- assignments and array-assignments, is there any method to get the speed of non-array-variable-assigments and the dynamics of arrays?**

I cannot use `var variable_$i = 1` in a loop so that $i is converted to some integer. I have to use `var variable[i] = 1` which is significantly slower than `var variable1 = 1` as the test proved. This may be critical only when there are large arrays and in many cases they are.

---

EDIT: 
I made a new test to confirm the slowness of arrays access and tried to find faster way:

http://jsperf.com/read-write-array-vs-variable

Array-read and/or array-write are significantly slower than using normal variables. If some operations are done to array members, it's wiser to store the array member value to a temp variable, make those operations to temp variable and finally store the value into the array member. And although code becomes larger, it's significantly faster to make those operations inline than in loop.

**Conclusion:** arrays vs normal variables are analogous to disk vs memory. Usually memory access is faster than disk access and normal variables access is faster than array access. And may be concatenating operations is also faster than using intermediate variables, but this makes code a little non readable.

---

Comment: What Javascript engine? Is the code such that JIT has a chance?

Comment: Arrays are not evil, but they are objects and they do so much awesome stuff that you don't have to worry about.  They have the handy `length` property as well as methods for filtering/sorting, etc.  If you don't need those features, you could try something like `window["varname_" + i]` to have an "array" of variable values, but it doesn't seem like you tested that.

Comment: are you preallocating your arrays?  if not does it make a difference?  `new Array(1000)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I assume that `window["varname_" + i]` means that "varname" + i has to be in global scope? But I don't understand why this "awesome stuff" cannot be made without the speed decrease in assigning values.

Comment: @vonbrand: the web browser, whichever engine.

Comment: @Timo perhaps you can find that out if you write your own JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle: http://jsperf.com/pre-filled-array/3 Nearly the same performance when using `var arr = new Array(10)` and `var arr = []`. Only prefilling the array with zeros make huge speedup in FF18 and some speedup in Chrome24.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Some reason there have to be. I'd thought that variable points to some location in memory and array member is a variable like other variables. So `arr[0]=1` and `variable=1` should have not so big speed difference. Maybe the reason is my MacBook.

Comment: @Timo this has nothing to do with memory, it has to do with execution speed.  Array assignment is more complex because there is additional derefencing *at least*

Answer (score 4):

> Assigning values to arrays is significantly slower than assigning to normal variables. Arrays are evil! This is very sad and I really don't understand why this occurs. Arrays are so important!

That's because normal variables are statically scoped and can be (and are) easily optimised. The compiler/interpreter will learn their type, and might even avoid repeated assignments of the same value.

These kind of optimisations will be done for arrays as well, but they're not so easy and will need longer to take effect. There is additional overhead when resolving the property reference, and since JavaScript arrays are auto-growing lists the length needs to be checked as well.

Prepopulating the arrays will help to avoid reallocations for capacity changes, but for your little arrays (`length`=10) it shouldn't make much difference.

> Is there any method to get the speed of non-array-variable-assigments and the dynamics of arrays?

No. Dynamics do cost, but they are worth it - as are loops.

You hardly ever will be in the case to need such a micro-optimisation, [don't try it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation). The only thing I can think of are fixed-sized loops (n <= 4) when dealing with `ImageData`, there inlining is applicable.

> Push is evil!

Nope, only your test was flawed. The jsperf snippets are executed in a timed loop without tearup and -down, and only there you have been resetting the size. Your repeated `push`es have been producing arrays with lengths of hundredth thousands, with correspondent need of memory (re-)allocations. See the console at http://jsperf.com/pre-filled-array/11.

Actually `push` is just as fast as property assignment. Good measurements are rare, but those that are done properly show varying results across different browser engine versions - changing rapidly and unexpected. See [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351409/1048572), [Why is array.push sometimes faster than array[n] = value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/614126/1048572) and [Is there a reason JavaScript developers don't use Array.push()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15649899/1048572) - the conclusion is that you should use what is most readable / appropriate for your use case, not what you think could be faster.

Comment: I don't even understand this post... Is this a question?  How did it get upvoted 5 times and favorited once? Thanks for answering correctly anyways.

Comment: @mikeyUX: Yup, it's much too long (and the calculations section seems completely unrelated), but deep down there's an actual question. Use `Strg`+`F` for `Question` to find it :-)

Comment: Long it it is, well. Sorry about that. It has flaws (regarding push evilness, thanks @Bergi about finding that). The measurements are done to find out the most performant variable handling to use in Clipper (http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.2.1.0/main_demo.html). It uses arrays of arrays filled with vertex objects with properties X and Y and possibly Z.

Comment: I have considered to replace this like structure with typed arrays and replace [{X:0,Y:1},{X:0,Y:1},{X:0,Y:1}] structure with Xs = [0,0,0], Ys = [1,1,1]. However it would require a complete recoding throughout the codebase, and would make it harder to keep JS version in sync with Angus Johnson's original C# version.