# Undefined values in Array(len) initializer

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Consider:

```
var a = Array(3);
var b = [undefined,undefined,undefined];
```

What's the reason that `a.map` and `b.map` produce different results?

```
a.map(function(){  return 0;  });  //produces -> [undefined,undefined,undefined]
b.map(function(){  return 0;  });  //produces -> [0,0,0]
```

Comment: Related: check out what happens if you set `b.length = 5;` before you run the `map`: `[0, 0, 0, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: hi dear Engineer, is there any possibility to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The array constructor creates an array with the given length. It does **not** create the keys. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'s callback function is only executed for the elements in the list.
That is, all values which are associated with a key (integer) 0 ≤ *i* < *length*.

- `Array(3)` has zero keys, so `.map`'s callback is never triggered.
- `[void 0, void 0, void 0]` has three keys, for which the callback function is executed.

  ```
  Array(3).hasOwnProperty(0);                 // false
  [void 0, void 0, void 0].hasOwnProperty(0); // true
  ```

The specification and its [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) are mentioned at MDN. At line 47, `if (k in O) {` shows that non-existant keys are not treated by the callback function.

Comment: Actually, map should iterate not over the keys, but over the sequence of values 0..array.length-1

Comment: @panda-34 Skipping keys between 0 and n is similar to walking over the numeric keys. But you're correct, strictly speaking, I should have said such ;)

Comment: @RobW Can we assume, that `Array(3)` does not *really allocate memory* for storing `3` elements,which values are `undefined`, and it simply sets `length` property to `3`, just it?

Comment: You didn't say "numeric", and non-numeric keys will be ignored by map and as such stripped from the result, which is not a hairsplitting distinction. And numeric is also not correct, all floating-point and negative-integer numeric keys (uh... they're all strings, really...) will also meet the fate of non-numerics.

Comment: @Engineer Yes. Verification is easy: Open Chrome's devtools (Ctrl+Shift+J) and the built-in task manager (Shift+Esc), and enter `window.x=Array(1e9);`. You don't see a significant increase in memory usage. `ArrayBuffer`, on the other hand: `x=new ArrayBuffer(1e9);` shows an increased memory consumption.

Answer (score 5):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which
>   have never been assigned values.

For the array `a`, you've instantiated an array of length 3 but have not assigned any values. The map function finds no elements with assigned values, so it does not produce a new array.

For the array `b`, you've instantiated an array of 3 elements, each with the value `undefined`. The map function finds 3 elements with assigned values, and returns '0' as the new value for each of them in a new array.

Answer (score 5):

`map` only iterates existing properties, not empty indices.

Therefore, if you want it to work, you must first fill the array.

There are multiple ways to do that, for example:

- [`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), introduced in ES6

  ```js
  console.log(new Array(3).fill().map(function(){ return 0; }));
  ```
- Call [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

  ```js
  var arr = [].concat.apply([], new Array(3));
  console.log(arr.map(function(){ return 0; }));
  ```
- An old `for` loop.

  ```js
  var arr = new Array(3);
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) arr[i] = 1; /* whatever */
  console.log(arr.map(function(){ return 0; }));
  ```
- Use some idea from [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1295584/1529630)
- Etcetera.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is an empty array that doesn't have elements, so map function produces empty array without elements *(per specification, map produces results only if [[HasProperty]] is true.)* `b` is an array of three elements, so map produces an array of three elements.

Answer (score 2):

### Constructed arrays are enumerable but empty

`Array(len)` creates an array and sets its length accordingly *but* only its length is "enumerable", not the values contained. So, you cannot map the array `Array(100).map(/* nope */)`— it's not a "real array" *yet* and  it is actually empty despite having the correct length.

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array **which have assigned values including undefined.**,

The `array` does not contain any values; not even `undefined`

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

To populate array you need to iterate it someway… E.g.: `[...Array(100)]` or `Array.from(Array(100))`

I imagine the purpose of this initialization is to optimize memory allocation… there isn't really anything in the array. MDN says "empty `arrayLength` objects" which might be misleading as trying to access any of the "empty items" just returns undefined… But we know they aren't really `undefined` since `map` fails, therefore we can confirm it is a truly empty array.

### Constructor equivalent

This example does not seek to mirror specification but instead to illustrate why an `array` returned from `Array` cannot yet be iterated

```js
function * (length) {
  const arr = [];
  Object.defineProperty(arr, 'length', { value: length });
  // Equivalent, but invokes assignment trap and mutates array:
  // arr.length = length;
  Object.defineProperty(arr, Symbol.iterator, {
    value() {
      let i = 0;
      return {
        next() {
          return {
            value: undefined, // (Not omitted for illustration)
            done: i++ == length
          };
        }
      }
    }
  })
  return arr;
}
```

It is worth pointing out that despite providing a `undefined` value in the generator value property, *it does not recognize it as a value and so the array is empty*.

### `Array(len)` Specification

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len

> Array (len) This description applies if and only if the Array
>   constructor is called with exactly one argument.
>
> 1) Let `numberOfArgs` be the number of arguments passed to this function
>   call.
>
> 2) Assert: `numberOfArgs` = 1.
>
> 3) If NewTarget is `undefined`, let `newTarget` be the active function object, else let `newTarget` be `NewTarget`.
>
> 4) Let `proto` be `GetPrototypeFromConstructor(newTarget, "%ArrayPrototype%")`.
>
> 5) `ReturnIfAbrupt(proto)`.
>
> 6) Let array be `ArrayCreate(0, proto)`.
>
> 7) If Type(`len`) is not Number, then
>
> *a) Let `defineStatus` be `CreateDataProperty(array, "0", len)`.*
>
> *b) Assert: `defineStatus` is true.*
>
> *c) Let `intLen` be 1.*
>
> 8) Else, *a) Let `intLen` be ToUint32(`len`). b) If `intLen` ≠ `len`, throw a RangeError exception.*
>
> 9) Let
>   `setStatus` be Set(array, "length", intLen, true).
>
> 10) Assert: `setStatus` is not an abrupt completion.
>
> 11) Return array.