# Why can't I create a random array using _.map(new Array(n), Math.random)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to make an array of random numbers between 0 and 1, so I tried:

```
var randList = _.map(new Array(5), Math.random);
```

But instead of getting the list of random elements that I expected, I got:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(randList));
"[null,null,null,null,null]"
```

Why did I get an Array of null instead of random numbers?

Comment: In Chrome, with native `Array.map()`:  `(new Array(5)).map(Math.random)` fails as above except the values are `undef`, not `null`. `[undefined,undefined].map(Math.random)` works OK!  `[0,0,0,0,0].map(Math.random)` also works OK.

Comment: Seems like underscore uses the native `.map` method inside. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11266126/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array(length)` constructor creates a sparse array. That is, the length of the array is set to the specified parameter, but the elements of the array are not populated. As a result, the `map` method does not iterate over these 'unpopulated' elements. For example, the following snippet does not produce any output on the console:

```
var arr = new Array(5);
for(var x in arr) console.log(x);
```

Note, however, that initializing the array like this will produce the expected result:

```
console.log(_.map([0,0,0,0,0], Math.random));
```

Of course, this doesn't scale. If you want the number of elements in the array to be variable, I would recommend you use the [`times`](http://underscorejs.org/#times) method instead:

```
var randList = _(5).times(Math.random);
```

or

```
var randList = _.times(5, Math.random);
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers the implied question of "the right way" to do this, but can you answer the question as to why this doesn't work? I'll check you off then :)

Comment: @cabbagebot Sorry, I've updated my answer for completeness. As usual, it's more difficult to explain why something doesn't work than it is to provide a working alternative. :P

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you get an array of `undefined` - and function passed into `map` isn't fired even once. That happens because array created with `new Array(Number)` constructor is a bit weird - even though its length is set up correctly, it doesn't actually have `0`, `1` etc. properties:

```
var arr = Array(5);
console.log(arr.length); // 5
console.log('0' in arr); // false
```

That's why, even though plain old `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` will work for iterating over this array, `for (var i in arr)` won't work:

```
for (var i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // won't be called even once!
}
```

And that's, I suppose, is more-o-less similar to what happens with Array.map (at which _.map is mapped):

```
var newarr = arr.map(function(el) {
   console.log(el); // nope, still nothing
});
console.log(newarr); // [undefined x 5]
```

---

So what's the right way of creating such an array? Here it is:

```
var rightArr = Array.apply(0, Array(5)); // ah, the pure magic of apply!
// and here goes an array of randoms:
var randArr = rightArr.map(Math.random);
```

... but of course using `_.times` is the way to go in this case. )

Comment: So it's really a "sparse array of no [property] elements"?

Comment: Yes, sort of. It's shown as `[null, null...]` only because of JSON quirk (which doesn't differentiate between `undefined` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add some test cases to raina77ow's excellent answer.

Indeed, new Array(5) doesn't alloc 5 properties in the Array object.

It's doesn't matter whether you use underscore or plain javascript Array.prototype.map (in decent browser of course).

**Here are test cases in node.js**

new Array(2) just returns an empty object (no keys) with 2 (kind of fake) placeholders

```
> var a = new Array(2);
> a;
[ ,  ]
> a.length;
2
> Object.keys(a);
[]
```

the map result is also an empty object (no keys) with 2 placeholders

```
> var result = a.map(Math.random);
> result;
[ ,  ]
> result.length;
2
> Object.keys(result);
[]
```

Why the result is an array object of length 2, even when there is nothing done?

Read the Array.prototype.map polyfill implmentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The map result was created as `var res = new Array(source_array_length);`

In addition, map works with a filled Array even when values are `undefined`

```
> [undefined, undefined].map(Math.random);
[ 0.6572469582315534, 0.6343784828204662 ]
```

Ok, let's also test sparse array, length is 2 but it only contains one key '1'.

```
> var a = []; a[1] = 'somthing';
> a;
[ , 'somthing' ]
> a.length
2
> Object.keys(a);
[ '1' ]
```

The map result returns an array of length 2, but only one key '1', only one Math.random is fired!

```
> var result = a.map(Math.random);
undefined
> result.length
2
> result
[ , 0.8090629687067121 ]  // only one Math.random fired.
> Object.keys(result);
[ '1' ]
```