# JavaScript Map: Why does this not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to generate some random data using map. To my surprise, I couldn't figure out why this code isn't working.

Consider the following snippet which works as expected:

```
const empty = [undefined, undefined];
const rand = empty.map(item => Math.random());

Output: [0.4774752874308936, 0.8482276976659398]
```

I tried to simplify a bit and do the following

```
const rand = Array(2).map(item => Math.random())

Output: [undefined × 2]
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Clearly, both arrays generated by Array(n) and [] are typical arrays and have all prototype methods.

```
Array(2) instanceof Array
true

[undefined, undefined] instanceof Array
true

Array.isArray(Array(2))
true

Array.isArray([undefined, undefined])
true
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong here?

Comment: btw - you can work around it by using `fill` - `Array(2).fill(null).map(item => Math.random())`

Comment: There's also `const rand = [...Array(2)].map(item => Math.random());` ;-)

Comment: Love that one :) Or even shorter: `[...Array(2)].map(Math.random);`

Comment: @Me.Name: Good point! [The definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-math.random) of `Math.random` makes no use of `this`.

Comment: Or `Array.from({ length: 2 }, Math.random);`

Comment: @OriDrori: ***That's*** what I was trying to remember. I'd remembered it as `[...{length:2}]`, but of course, plain objects have no iterator. It was the `Array.from` part I'd forgotten.

Comment: Oh, I like SO questions like this.  @OriDrori idea is neat, extending to do other stuff like Array of squares ->  `Array.from({length:11},(i,ix) => ix*ix)`

Comment: See also [Why does `.forEach` work on dense arrays but not on sparse arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28974006/1048572) and [Why can't I create a random array using `_.map(new Array(n), Math.random)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22738287/1048572)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Array(2)` gives you an **empty** array with a length of `2`. JavaScript arrays are inherently *sparse* (they can have holes in them, because [they aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)¹), and that's what `Array(2)` gives you. It looks like this:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    (array)   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| length: 2    |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

whereas your `[undefined, undefined]` array looks like this:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    (array)   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| length: 2    |
| 0: undefined |
| 1: undefined |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`map`, `forEach`, and *most* (but not all) of the related methods on `Array.prototype` only loop through the *actual entries* of a sparse array. Since the array returned by `Array(2)` doesn't have any actual entries, your callback is never being called.

ES2015 added [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) (and it can be shimmed), which you can use to fill an array:

```js
const rand = Array(2).fill().map(Math.random)
console.log(rand);
```

(Note that as [Me.Name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431042/me-name) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928967/javascript-map-why-does-this-not-work/40929008#comment69069559_40928967) we don't need `item => Math.random`,  we can call `Math.random` directly; it doesn't use `this` or its arguments ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-math.random)).)

There's also this trick for creating a *filled* array with `undefined`s in it:

```
const empty = [...Array(2)]:
```

...which you could apply like this if you didn't want `fill`:

```js
const rand = [...Array(2)].map(Math.random);
console.log(rand);
```

[Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928967/javascript-map-why-does-this-not-work/40929008#comment69069745_40928967) that we can do

```
Array.from({length: 2}, Math.random);
```

e.g.:

```js
const rand = Array.from({length: 2}, Math.random);
console.log(rand);
```

And [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)  [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928967/javascript-map-why-does-this-not-work/40929012?noredirect=1#comment69070255_40929008) the classic, ES5-compatible:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 2}).map(Math.random);
```

```js
var rand = Array.apply(null, {length: 2}).map(Math.random);
console.log(rand);
```

---

¹ *(That's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Answer (score 4):

You could look into the specs of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

You could use Array.apply for getting an iterabel array with map.

```js
console.log(Array.apply(null, { length: 2 }).map(Math.random));
```

Comment: *"You could look into the specs of `Array#map`"* MDN isn't "the specs." It's secondary documentation. (*Very good* secondary documentation.) [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map) is the spec.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you assume that `Array(2)` is interpreted by the JavaScript engine somewhat like this: "Create an array object with two entries initialized to a default value, say 0 or `undefined`".

Actually, the JavaScript engine creates a new object and sets its `length` property to 2. It does not have any real content.

Check this very simple example:

```js
var arr = new Array(2);
console.log(arr);
```

If you run it and check the console you're going to see something like this:

```
Array[2] => {
    length: 2,
    __proto__: Array[0]
}
```

No contents, no placeholders. Just an empty array with `length` initialized to 2.

That is why your arrow function never gets called.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating an array initialized with size of 2. But there isn´t any element in these positions. then you do
`[undefined, undefined].map(item => Math.random())`

You have an array with two undefined elements in it.

Comment: This means nothing, the initial value is irrelevant, it's the Math.random() that would be the value applied. You should've also realized this from the fact that the first example worked. The .map method is essentially an assignment for every element in an array.

Comment: I do not understand. What I am saying is that doing Array(2) you are not filling the array with elements. Just defining the lenght. And doing [undefined, undefined] you are filling the array with elements so map function will iterate the elements

Comment: Riiiight, well from what you said I got the impression you were implying that they are one in the same, i.e. that initializing an array of size 2 creates [undefined, undefined], which would expect the same result as the first example. Might have been why someone voted you down, but I don't know (it wasn't me).