# Difference between Array(1) and [...Array(1)]

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the difference between `Array(1)` and `[...Array(1)]`? I was sure that both are equivalent until I saw that both behave differently regarding `.map`:

```js
console.log(Array(1).map(() => 1));
console.log([...Array(1)].map(() => 1));
```

Why do they behave differently even though both return `[undefined]`?

```js
console.log(Array(1));
console.log([...Array(1)]);
```

Comment: `Array(1)` creates an array with 1 empty slot. Spreading it makes an array with one item which is `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ That means that an empty slot and `undefined` are different but when I try to access an empty spot I get `undefined`?

Comment: @jabaa [Yes, they're different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266126/undefined-values-in-arraylen-initializer), even if accessing them gives `undefined` for both

Comment: So many duplicates and I haven't found even one of them

Comment: @jabaa yes. If you have an object `obj = {a: 1, c: 3}` then `obj.b` will give you `undefined`. That's what an empty slot is - it doesn't exist. But if you try to read its value, you get `undefined`. Array iteration methods such as `.map` will skip over empty slots and only act on existing items, even if those items are `undefined`.

Comment: Well you can find them only if you know exactly what to search for… (or have bookmarked them) and I found one but VLAZ found another.