# Predefining Array Length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

Is there a performance boost to predefining the length of a Javascript array when pushing items into that array?

For instance, suppose you're doing this:

```
var item1 = "apple",
    item2 = "orange",
    item3 = "sports car"; // Because I said so, that's why.

var myArray = [];  // Empty array with initial length of 0

myArray.push(item1);
console.log(myArray.length) // 1

myArray.push(item2);
console.log(myArray.length) // 2

myArray.push(item3);
console.log(myArray.length) // 3
```

In the above code the length of myArray is recalculated on each push.  Alternatively;

```
var item1 = "apple",
item2 = "orange",
item3 = "sports car";

var myArray = Array(3) // Assume we already know exactly how many items will be added
myArray[0] = item1;
console.log(myArray.length) // 3

myArray[1] = item2;
console.log(myArray.length) // 3

myArray[2] = item3;
console.log(myArray.length) // 3
```

My question is this, when you explicitly assign a value to a pre-existing slot within an array is the length property of that array still re-evaluated.  If not, does sidestepping that process yield faster array population?

It should go without saying that this is more of a theoretical exercise than an actual real-world problem.

Comment: Some people doing benchmarks on a very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array

Comment: Array literals are faster because you don't need to invoke the constructor (or run an extra function), but I'm not sure about your particular question. I doubt it makes a _real_ difference.

Comment: I would guess that setting the length beforehand might speed up the insertion later.

Comment: I suppose the length property is not re-evaluated, it will always be 3 ! I mean if you don''t add `myArray[2] = item3;` still the length will show 3 not 2, since the 3rd slot will take a default value

Comment: Jsperf is great for real world tests of this sort of thing. Your test.. http://jsperf.com/pre-allocated-arrays/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/arraysforjosh), predefining length *is* faster, by quite a bit.

It should be noted that `new Array()` syntax isn't exactly considered best practice.  If you *absolutely need* to squeeze every last bit of performance, consider this.  Otherwise, make life easy for you and all the developers who touch your code, use `[]`.

Comment: It's not quite comparing apples to apples there, since your second example isn't using push, which is typically a bit slower than just assigning the index. It would be interesting to see all variations (defined/not defined length, push/assign by index). But an interesting result.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I'll add a non-push version.