# What is possible functional substition for "for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)" loop?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want plain vanilla solution. I am writing a lot of 
`for (var i = 0; i < someSize; i++) {...}`

Please note that it's not for iterating an array or *DOM* nodes it's mainly for pure calculations.

I would like more functional approach because I am *lazy*. Something like:

`new Array(15).forEach(function(i, idx) {
   ...
   ...
})`

But this doesn't work.

When using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) I used to write

`_.range(0,100,4).forEach(function(i, idx) {
  doSomethingWith(i);
});`

Please not that it may not be practical but I like to bend Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For each in an array. How to do that in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)

Comment: Why make up an array just to iterate through a sequence of numbers?  Why not just make a helper function that does the iteration (as in my answer)?  I guess I'm puzzled why you think making a dummy array just so you can iterate a sequence of numbers is the desired solution here?

Comment: You are right, I am creating a dummy array just because of `forEach`. It looks like your answer is the most suitable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you really want, but you can just have a generic iterator function that manages the loop counter for you:

```
function loop(start, stop, fn) {
   for (var i = start; i < stop; i++) {
       if (fn(i) === false) {
           return;
       }
   }
}
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
loop(0, size, function(i) {
    // use i here
});
```

---

You could even make the start value optional (defaulting to zero if not present):

```
function loop(start, stop, fn) {
   if (!fn) {
      fn = stop;
      stop = start;
      start = 0;
   }
   for (var i = start; i < stop; i++) {
       if (fn(i) === false) {
           return;
       }
   }
}

loop(size, function(i) {
    // use i here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I havent though of a simple generic solution and was looking for some `magic`! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this isn't working, seems to be because `forEach` isn't iterating the `undefined` values that are set when using the array constructor like that.

`forEach` works fine for arrays that actually have contents, as you will seen when you run code like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].forEach(function(){console.log(arguments)});
```

So, now, all you'd be looking for would be to properly initialize a new array, with contents.

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array) has some useful answers in that regard.
The shortest solution seems to be:

```
new Array(5+1).join('0').split('')
```

You can simply chain the `forEach` after that.

Or, you can whip up a prototype from one of the more upvoted answers in that question:

```
Array.prototype.init = function(value, length){
    return Array.apply(null, new Array(length)).map(function(){
        return value.valueOf();
    },value);
}
```

That allows you to do something like this:

```
[].init('foo', 3);
// ["foo", "foo", "foo"]
[].init(60, 4);
// [60, 60, 60, 60]
[].init({}, 3);
// [{},{},{}]
[].init(true, 9);
// [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

You can of course chain a `.forEach()` after `init()`.

(Actually, if you don't add this function to `Array.prototype`, you can just use `init()`, without the Array literal. That might be a "cleaner" solution)

Comment: Thanks. As for `new Array(5).join('').split('').forEach()` it seems like an overkill for me :)

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: I agree :P How about the prototype I suggested? If you use it a lot, that might be worth it.

Comment: I do not mind adding things to `prototype` and your solution is really brilliant, thanks for that too!