# Why does Array.apply(null, [args]) act inconsistently when dealing with sparse arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently discovered the following [snippet of code on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735425/1139652) to aid in quickly populating an array with default values:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(3)).map(function() {return 0;});
```

Given the behavior of the Array constructor and the apply method, the above snippet can also be rewritten as such:

```
Array.apply(null, [undefined, undefined, undefined]).map(function() {return 0;});
```

This technique is also useful when dealing with sparse arrays that you wish to populate with default values:

```
var sparseArr = [3,,,4,1,,],
    denseArr = Array.apply(null, sparseArr).map(function(e) {
      return e === undefined ? 0 : e;
    });

// denseArr = [3,0,0,4,1,0]
```

However it is therein that two oddities arise:

1. If the final term of of `sparseArr` is undefined, that term  is not mapped in `denseArr`
2. If `sparseArr` contains only a single term (e.g. `sparseArr = [1]`) or a single term followed by a single trailing undefined term (e.g. `sparseArr = [1,]`), the resulting `denseArr` equals `[undefined x 1]`

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `new Array(3)` […] can also be rewritten as `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

No - as you just have seen, the array constructor creates sparse arrays so it should be rewritten as `[,,,]`.

> If the final term of of sparseArr is undefined

Nope. You're forgetting about trailing commata, which are optional since EcmaScript 5. Actually `[1]` is just equivalent to `[1,]` (both have a length of `1`).

To get sparse "slots", you will have to add additional commata:

```
[] // empty array
[,] // empty array
[,,] // [undefined x 1]
[,,,] // [undefined x 2]
```

> If `sparseArr` contains only a single term, the resulting `denseArr` equals `[undefined x N]`

Consider what it means to call the [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
Array.apply(null, [3,,4,1]) ≡ Array(3, undefined, 4, 1)
Array.apply(null, [3,4]) ≡ Array(3, 4)
Array.apply(null, [1]) ≡ Array(1)
```

And you know what the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) does when being called with a single numeric arguments - it creates a sparse array of that length…

Comment: That's interesting about the trailing comma I didn't know about that. However this doesn't answer my second point regarding the strange behavior of arrays with 1 element. In the example given, if `sparseArr = [1]`, `denseArr` will equal `[undefined x 1]`. Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Uh, I didn't notice that second point at first because you mixed the first behaviour into its description… Answer updated.

Comment: Wow, the plural of "comma" is "commata". Huh.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a trailing comma in arrays since ECMA 262. Its presence doesn't modify   the content of the array in any way.

If you have two or more consecutive non trailing commas inside an array, their content is set as undefined.

Note: since `undefined` in arrays has nonstandard behaviour in IE<9 I would avoid using it there. Use `null` instead.

The fact that you have surprising results when sparseArr contains one item is because Array has two different constructors: if you pass it multiple arguments it creates an array with that sequence, if you pass it a single number it creates an array of length "number" filled with undefined.

```
new Array(1, 2, 3)
=> [1, 2, 3]

new Array(2)
=> [undefined, undefined]
```