# What is Array.apply actually doing

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

After reading [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949976/why-does-array-applynull-args-act-inconsistently-when-dealing-with-sparse-a), I'm still a little confused as to what Array.apply is actually doing. Consider the following snippet:

```
new Array(5).map(function(){
  return new Array(5);
});
```

I expect this to init an array with 5 undefined entries, then map over them creating a two dimensional array of 5x5);

Instead I just get the array as if it was never mapped over:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

When I wrap the constructor call to array in an Array.apply call, then map over that, it works as expected:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(function(){
  return new Array(5);
});
```

resulting in;

```
[[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]];
```

What's the deal? Is Array.apply just another way of calling new Array(), or Array.prototype.constructor? Are there any other situations where this would be advantageous? Also, why didn't my first approach pick up on the map I was sending it through?

Thanks!
-Neil

Comment: Worth mentioning for anyone who wants to bypass the confusing Array.apply(null... thing, that you can do **`Array(5).fill(Array(5))`** to get an array of five sparse 5-length arrays; or **`Array(someLength).fill(someDefault).map(someFunction)`** to map someFunction over an array of someLength. For example `Array(1000).fill(1).map((n,i) => n+i)` gives you an array of numbers from 1 to 1000

Answer (score 83):

Good question!

The `Array` constructor function (with can be used without `new`), when passed more than 1 argument, creates an array containing the arguments passed in as its elements. So you can do this:

```
Array(1, 2, 3); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

As you probably know, `Function.prototype.apply` allows you to provide arguments to a function in the form of an array. So calling `Array.apply` (which just inherits its `.apply()` method from Function's prototype; any function that is an instance of Function would allows you to do this), which will be functionality equivalent to the code above:

```
Array.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Now, here's why things are a bit confusing. The `Array.prototype.map` method is spec'd in such a way that it deals with *sparse arrays* specially. A sparse array is one that has a "length" that is greater than the number of elements that have actually been inserted. For example:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 'foo';
arr[5] = 'bar';
```

The array constructed above will have a `length` property of 6, because it has an element at index 0 and one at index 5. *However*, since no elements were ever inserted between those indices, if you call `map` on it you'll see that the mapping function does not get applied to the missing elements:

```
// This should throw, right? Since elements 1 through 4 are undefined?
var lengths = arr.map(function(s) { return s.length; });

// Nope!
lengths; // => [3, , , , , 3]
```

And why are we seeing this behavior in your example with `new Array(5)`? You guessed it: because the array constructor, when given a single argument, creates a *sparse* array with the specified length.

So the issue here is that while `map` (and other methods on `Array.prototype`, such as `forEach`) behaves specially with respect to sparse arrays by skipping over the missing values, the `Function.prototype.apply` method does not have any such special behavior.

Comment: So, in one case, the indexes weren't defined, and in the other, the indexes were defined as undefined?

Comment: @KevinB: It almost makes me sad to say it, but... yep. This is the same reason why `arr[1] = undefined`; is *not* functionality equivalent to `delete arr[1];`

Comment: @DanTao Thanks for the explanation. If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that when I use Array.apply, I'm actually using the Function.prototype instead of the Array.prototype?

Comment: @Neil Yes. Array.apply is used because both map and apply are defined for Array but only apply is defined for Function.

Comment: I propose this to be selected as the answer

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Function.prototype.apply` not only decomposes arrays, but also "array like" objects. This mean these two are functionally equivalent: `Array.apply(null, { length: 5 })` == `Array.apply(null, Array(5))`. You decide which one is more readable

Comment: I think someone should mention here that if you are not careful with this, you'll end up with an stack overflow on your hands. An example would be writing `Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(...`. For big values of n you will insert a lot of stuff in your stack breaking your software. I would recomend avoiding this kind of hackish stuff alltogether and use something like `Array(n).fill(undefined)` instead.

Comment: I first learned about `Array.apply(null, { length: n })` thing when trying to generate a large quantity of random numbers: `Array.apply(null, { length: 1e5 }).map(Function.call, Math.random)`.

Answer (score 15):

It is very intresting example. And pretty good answer by Dan Tao. But I think that I can give a little additional explanation.

In the first case

> new Array(5)

creates an empty object, then it passes throw function and gived length of 5. Because of missing any other arguments this object will get no allocated entries.

```
// Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ]
```

And when you trying to "map" those entries nothing actualy happened because of missing real entries.

However, if you try after this step "array[0]" for example, it returns "undefined"...

In the next case you are using "Call" method of Array() function after first "new Array(5)" (but actualy it has no differense "Call" or "Construct" method of call is used with Array function).

> Array.apply(null, new Array(5))

So "new Array(5)" already gived as result Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ] and "Function.prototype.apply()" decomposes this array to the five parameters that Array() function gets in. And in the current step we get:

```
// Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

These are five real entries. And we can do "map()" with them. But there is a litle mistake in your result, because we currently get after

> Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(function() {   return new Array(5);
>   });

a little bit different result

```
/*
[…]    
0: Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ]    
1: Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ]  ​  
2: Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ] ​    
3: Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ] ​    
4: Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ]
*/
```

and to get more precise, to get "five on five, undefined" result we need to little upgrade your code

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(function(){ return Array.apply(null,new Array(5)); });
```

this will return "five on five, undefined" array.

```
/*
[…] 
0: Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, … ] 
1: Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, … ] 
2: Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, … ] 
3: Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, … ] 
4: Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, … ]
*/
```

But what I'm talking about is that not only "Function.prototype.apply()" has current behavior to decompose array without real entries. I'll give you an example:

```
Array(...new Array(5)).map(() => Array(...new Array(5)));
```

this will actualy gived to us exactly the same result - five on five undefined.

If we took a closer look:

1. In the first action `new Array(5)` Array() function returns an empty array but with length property value of '5' because it runs in "Construct" mode, and has one parameter (5).
2. The second and third action `Array.apply() | Array(...)`
   first of all spreads Array without elements to 5 parameters and then pass them to an Array().

It's because of "apply()" or "..." behavior of decomposing arrays. When it gets length of an array it auto transform "empty slots" into undefined values.

Referense from Ecma-262/6.0

(http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply)

```
19.2.3.1 Function.prototype.apply
    1. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    2. If argArray is null or undefined, then Return Call(func, thisArg).
    3. Let argList be CreateListFromArrayLike(argArray).

    7.3.17 CreateListFromArrayLike (obj [, elementTypes] )     
        1. ReturnIfAbrupt(obj).
        2. If elementTypes was not passed, let elementTypes be (Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, Object).
        3. If Type(obj) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
        4. Let len be ToLength(Get(obj, "length")).
        5. ReturnIfAbrupt(len).
        6. Let list be an empty List.
        7. Let index be 0.
        8. Repeat while index < len
            a. Let indexName be ToString(index).
            b. Let next be Get(obj, indexName).
            c. ReturnIfAbrupt(next).
            d. If Type(next) is not an element of elementTypes, throw a TypeError exception.
            e. Append next as the last element of list.
            f. Set index to index + 1.
        9. Return list.
```

1. Here in '8a' clause we get "0", "1"... indexNames to pass them in '8b' as argument names of arraylike object (in our case just array, without any 'like') - array["0"], array["1"]...
2. Each of requested element values returns with "undefined" and then in 8'e' they consecutively appends to the arguments list.
3. "CreateListFromArrayLike" returns with five arguments of undefined in list representation in '9'clause which is passed to Function.prototype.apply() and will be applied to an Array() (it will be looking like

`new Array(undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined)`).

Spread operator uses iteration protokol instead, but in practice they act simulary on this case.

Answer (score 2):

The Array constructor , when passed with a single numeric value (Let's say n) , creates a sparse Array of length n and has zero elements in it... so .map() wont work on it as explained by Dan Tao...

```
let ar = Array(5); // Array(5) [ <5 empty slots> ]
```

So , you can use .fill() method , that changes all elements in an array to given value, from a start index (default 0) to an end index (default array.length). It returns the modified array... 
So we can fill the empty (sparse) array with "undefined" value...
It won't be sparse anymore...And finally, you can use .map() on returned array...

```
let ar = Array(5).fill(undefined) ; // [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
let resultArray = ar.map(  el => Array(5).fill(undefined) );
```

this resultArray will be a 5*5 array with every value of undefined...

```
/* 
[ [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ] ]
*/
```

:)