# Difference between Array.apply(null, Array(x) ) and Array(x)

Tags: javascript

What exactly is the difference between:

```
Array(3)
// and
Array.apply(null, Array(3) )
```

The first returns `[undefined x 3]` while the second returns `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. The second is chainable through `Array.prototype.functions` such as `.map`, but the first isn't. Why?

Comment: `Array.apply(null, Array(9))` is *not* `new Array(9)`. It is spreading an `Array(9)` into `Array()` as nine parameters.  Even if it works it is pretty much the wrong way.  For example you can `new Array(1e7)` but not `Array.apply(null, Array(1e7))`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949976/why-does-array-applynull-args-act-inconsistently-when-dealing-with-sparse-a

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a difference, a quite significant one.

The `Array` constructor ***either*** accepts one single number, giving the lenght of the array, and an array with "empty" indices is created, or more correctly the length is set but the array doesn't really contain anything

```
Array(3); // creates [], with a length of 3
```

When calling the array constructor with a number as the only argument, you create an array that is empty, and that can't be iterated with the usual Array methods.

***Or***... the Array constructor accepts several arguments, whereas an array is created where each argument is a value in the array

```
Array(1,2,3); // creates an array [1,2,3] etc.
```

When you call this

```
Array.apply(null, Array(3) )
```

It get's a little more interesting.

`apply` accepts the `this` value as the first argument, and as it's not useful here, it's set to `null`

The interesting part is the second argument, where an empty array is being passed in.
As `apply` accepts an array it would be like calling

```
Array(undefined, undefined, undefined);
```

and that creates an array with three indices that's not empty, but have the value actually set to `undefined`, which is why it can be iterated over.

**TL;DR**
The main difference is that `Array(3)` creates an array with three indices that are empty. In fact, they don't really exist, the array just have a length of `3`.

Passing in such an array with empty indices to the Array constructor using `apply` is the same as doing `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined);`, which creates an array with three `undefined` indices, and `undefined` is in fact a value, so it's not empty like in the first example.

Array methods like `map()` can only iterate over actual values, not empty indices.

Answer (score 14):

The `.map()` API does not iterate over completely uninitialized array elements. When you make a new array with the `new Array(n)` constructor, you get an array with the `.length` you asked for but with non-existent elements that will be skipped by methods like `.map()`.

The expression `Array.apply(null, Array(9))` explicitly populates the newly-created array instance with `undefined`, but that's good enough. The trick is whether or not the `in` operator will report that the array contains an element at the given index. That is:

```
var a = new Array(9);
alert(2 in a); // alerts "false"
```

That's because there really is no element at position `2` in the array. But:

```
var a = Array.apply(null, Array(9));
alert(2 in a); // alerts "true"
```

The outer call to the Array constructor will have explicitly populated the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't really sure that what was 'in' each slot wasn't the same as the value undefined, since indexing into any given position returns undefined.

Comment: @mb_s88 consider `0 in Array(9); // false`

Comment: @mb_s88 answer extended a little bit

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3 `Function.prototype.apply` also doesn't really care if `argArray` is a true _Array_ as long as it is a readable _Object_, `Array.apply(null, {length: "2.5"}); // [undefined, undefined]`

Answer (score 6):

This is an artifact of how *apply* works. When you do:

```
new Array(9)
```

an empty array is created with a length of 9. *map* does not visit non–existent members, so does nothing at all. However, [*apply*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply) turns the array into a list using [*CreateListFromArrayLike*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createlistfromarraylike) so it turns the formerly empty array into a parameter list like:

```
[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined];
```

that is passed to *Array* to create an array with 9 members, all with a value of *undefined*. So now map will visit them all.

BTW, ECMAScript 2015 has [*Array.prototype.fill*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill) for this (also see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)) so you can do:

```
Array(9).fill(0);
```

Comment: The question is if performance-wise you're better off using Array.apply(null,length) or Array(length).fill()

Comment: @Jony-Y—not an important one. I'd use whichever suited my situation best, micro-optimisations should be the last consideration. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because the first array would not have ordered properties `arr[0] === undefined` and the second does. Array functions like forEach and map will iterate from 0 to the array's length - 1 and the lack of order to the properties of the first is an issue. The second version produces an array with the correct ordering, i.e.

```
arr = Array.apply(null, Array(3));
arr[0] === undefined //true
arr[1] === undefined //true
//etc.
```

The first version as you noticed doesn't. Also, adding `new` to the first version would not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you have one operation

> Array(3)

Its creates an array with three empty slots. Not an array with the three undefined values but exactly - empty.

At the second case

> Array.apply(null, Array(3) )

we can spread it to the three operations:

- first: Array(3) - you get an array with 3 empty slots;
- second: Array(3) spreads by Function.prototype.apply() function to 3 parameters that it passes to Array() function. At this stage 3 empty slots in given array transformes by apply() to 3 undefined values (it looks like if apply() sees an empty slot it automaticaly turns it to undefined in any sparsed array).
- third: we get an Array(undefined, undefined, undefined). And that will do to us an array with 3 undefined (not empty) values.

Because now you have 3 undefined but not empty slots, you can use them with map() function.

Note that not only Function.prototype.apply() have such behavior of decomposing arrays by such way. You can also do this in ECMAScript 6 by "..." - spread operator.

```
Array(...new Array(3));
```

This will also returns an array with 3 undefined and respectively can be mapped slots.

Here i giving more detailed explanation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814230/11715665