# Constructing Arrays using apply() vs new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, apply

I want to initialize an array of a given size with elements set to `undefined` by default.

`new Array(5)` returns an array of 5 empty items.
`Array.apply(null, Array(5))` returns exactly what I want: a five element array with each element as `undefined`.

Why does the second option produce a different array value than the first?

This distinction is important because I can map over an array of empty items but I can for undefined elements.

```
new Array(5).map(Boolean) // [false, false, false, false, false]

Array.apply(null, Array(5)) // [ <5 empty items>]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Array.apply actually doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512771/what-is-array-apply-actually-doing)

Answer (score 1):

`.map` is a native Array object method that is expected to return a value for every iteration over the array to create a new copied array from the array. `Boolean` can be used as a constructor function to create a boolean object with a `true` or `false` value. Try the same thing with `Number` like:

```
new Array(5).map(Number)
```

In your second example, `.apply` calls a function with a supplied [context](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-the-keyword-this-and-context-in-javascript-cd624c6b74b8/) value as the first parameter, and the parameter the function takes in as the second parameter. Also here, `Array` can be used as a constructor function, to construct a new Array (just like with `Number` and `Boolean` of their respective types)

Answer (score 0):

First of All, Javascript array is a Object. If you check this, you will understand it. ONly specialty is,it has length property that regular object in javascript.

```
var array = new Array(5) 
typeof array
```

And other thing is `Array.apply` mean, it will call array native function with setting given context which is null for your case and parameters are in another array.

```
Array.apply(null, [,,,,,]);
```

output will be  `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use Array.from

```js
console.log(Array.from({ length: 5 }))

// if you want to initialise the values you can add a constructor function

console.log(Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => index + 1))
```