# Why is the output [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] for this function on the following array?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var hello = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function (x, i) { return i; });
```

I get what map does, but I don't understand why the function does what it does to make the `hello == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: It is keys of the array of length 5. What makes you confused?

Comment: `Array.apply(null, Array(5))` returns an array of size full of `undefined`s. Whatever there is inside, this `map` function ignores values and converts it into array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] because second argument of `map` is index.

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949976/why-does-array-applynull-args-act-inconsistently-when-dealing-with-sparse-a

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter on the closure passed to `map` is the array key. That is what is being returned so you're getting 5 array keys, starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should break it down:

```
var arr = Array(5);
arr === [,,,,,];  // array with five undefined slots
arr === [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]; // same as this :)
```

Each has an index:

```
arr[4]; // yay! => undefined
```

`map` loops through each slot and the mapping function gets 2 params, the value and the index.

```
function (x, i) { return i; }
```

`map` produces an array of all the `return` values from the mapping function.

Comment: _"// array with five undefined slots"_ `[,,,,,]` has more than five elements :)

Comment: @Andreas I don't understand what you mean. :)  `Array(5) === [,,,,,]` right?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(Array(5)) -> "[null,null,null,null,null]"` compare the number of commas. There is one too many in your example.

Comment: @DavinTryon I think Andreas means that an empty array of length 5, would probably only have 4 commas, not 5 ;)

Comment: @Andreas did you test your theory?  It is JS afterall :)  The literal `[,,,,]` only has `undefined x 4` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out by performing a dry run of your code:

```
var hello = Array.apply(null, Array(5))
```

At this point:

```
hello == [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
```

Now:

```
hello.map(function (x, i) { return i; });
```

Is the equivalent to (use the comments to see how the below references the above function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < hello.length; i++){ // i is the index
    x = hello[i];                      // x is the value at each index

    // Function body below using `hello[i] = ` instead of return
    hello[i] = i;
}
```

Hence the result from setting each element in the list to the index of that element:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```