# Sum of values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript `matrix` array with the following structure (the first index is `x`, the second index is `y`, so every `x` item has 4 `y` items):

```
0 
  0 { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
  1 { x: 0, y: 1, z: 5}
  2 { x: 0, y: 2, z: 0}
  3 { x: 0, y: 3, z: 1}
1
  0 { x: 1, y: 0, z: 4}
  1 { x: 1, y: 1, z: 5}
  2 { x: 1, y: 2, z: 1}
  3 { x: 1, y: 3, z: 8}
```

What I need to do is get an array that stores the `z` values per `y` value. So for all the values of `x` I need the total values of `z` arranged by `y`. The structure I am looking for (assuming 4 `y` values)

```
0 4
1 10
2 1
3 9
```

I tried this:

```
count = [];
    $.each(matrix, function(i, j) {
      $.each(j, function(k, v) {
        count[k] += v["z"];
      })          
    });
```

But this returns just an array with `NaN` values. Does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Where are your array `var` definitions? Must they be arrays or can they be objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  initialize count array

```
var count=[ 0, 0, 0, 0];
$.each(matrix, function(i, j) {
  $.each(j, function(k, v) {
    count[k] += parseInt(v["z"],10);
  })          
});
```

Comment: Great, now could I initialize the `count` automatically with the length of the `y` array? So that I don't have to enter another `0` if the `y` array gains an item?

Comment: Never mind, I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

Your count array is not initialized, and you are trying to do math with `undefined`, so your result is `NaN`. Initialize `count` array with zeros.