# Javascript: Write a function that takes in a number, and returns an array with that number in it that many times

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, push

I'm a complete newbie to programming and mathematical concepts (took Math 101 in college) so I'm struggling with this problem:

> Write a function that takes in a number, and returns an array with that number in it that many times.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
    function numReturn(x) {
         var newArray = [];
         if (typeof x === "number") {
             return newArray.push[x]* x;
         } else {
             return null;
         }
     }
```

Here's my thought process:

1. Create a function that can take in a number, x.
2. Within that function, create a blank array so you can push values to it later.
3. Check if the `typeof` value entered in for x is a number. If it is, return it pushed to the end of the blank array. Otherwise, return `null`.

When I put this in the Javascript console and plug a value in, it comes back undefined. Anyone have some pointers for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do something an arbitrary number of times, one uses a *loop*. There are several loops, but here the `for` loop is most appropriate.

A `for` loop has the following structure:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    // ^initializer
    //         ^condition
    //                ^increment
    //body
}
```

The initializer is the first thing that is done **when entering** the loop. IN this case, it means a variable named `i` is set to `0`. Then the condition `x` is checked. If the condition `i < x` holds, the loop is executed: the body is executed. After the body is executed, the increment is performed (here `i++`), and then the condition is rechecked, if the condition still holds, the loop is executed again, and so on.

You can apply this concept as follows:

```
function numReturn(x) {
    var newArray = [];
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            newArray.push(x);
        }
        return newArray;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the explanation. I now know that the loop works by checking by pushing x "in a the array the number between x and 0, which is x.

Answer (score 3):

```
function a(i) {
    var a = new Array(i);
    return a.fill(i);
}
```

or `return new Array(i).fill(i);`, for short. Test:

```
a(4)
// --> [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

---

[Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is an ES6 method and is not yet universally implemented. Chrome and Firefox have it, IE does not - but there is a polyfill available.

Compare: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array.prototype_methods_Array.prototype.fill

Answer (score 1):

This: `newArray.push[x]* x` does not push x times. The * operator just multiplies numbers, always and only. You want to push x times, so use a `for` like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++ )
      newArray.push(x);
```

and then return `newArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from answer of [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array)

```
function numReturn(x){
    return Array.apply(null, Array(x)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,x);
}
console.log(numReturn(10)); // [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = 7
var result = Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(function(){return n})

// Demo output
document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

As function:

```
function numReturn(x) {
     if (typeof x === "number") {
         return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(function(){return n})
     } else {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Spectacular one-liner. I don't think the OP will learn much from it though.

Comment: @JohnWhite: my idea exactly. One here introduces JSON, higher order functions, all kinds of library functions, document,... This is simply too much to understand at once. It's like giving a typewriter to a monkey and expecting it to start typing Shakespear. (this comment is not meant as an offense to anybody).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want just to open his eyes so he can see that there is more ways to do it. The loop answer is already posted anyways.

Comment: Also the `.fill` is better for this, I learned something new!