# Creating array of length n with random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34693778/1525840) for creating an array of specified length, I executed the below to get a corresponding result but filled with random numbers, instead of zeros.

```
var randoms = Array(4).fill(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
```

Well, mathematically speaking **it's random**, all right. But I'd like the randomness to be visible within the array and not only between runs, of course. Stupid computer... Don't do what I say. Do what I want!

I can iterate and put it my random (and varying) values. But I wonder, of pure curiosity, if it's possible to get the right result with a one-liner, like above, MatLab-style. Do I need to call *eval(function()...)*? I've heard a lot of bad things about *eval*...

Note that the above produces code like this:

> [7, 7, 7, 7]
>   [3, 3, 3, 3]

etc. while I want something like

> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>   [4, 3, 8, 4]

Comment: I don't understand _But I'd like the randomness to be visible within the array and not only between runs, of course_. AFAIU, you just want to create an array of length `n` with random numbers.

Comment: @Tushar If you run the line in the console, you'll see... It creates **a single** random number and copies it in on all places as a fix number. First when you run again, you'll get a set of other numbers (all the same for each run). Easy to miss, huh? I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: "The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static [sic!] value." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah, that's what I recognized. It's a random value. True that. But not what I wanted. I recall a teacher claiming that there's no function for generating only prime numbers. I contradicted him by *function(){ return 13; }* He wasn't happy. Everybody else was amused.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I wonder if it's possible to get the right result with a one-liner...

```js
var randoms = [...Array(4)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

document.body.innerText = randoms;
```

Answer (score 29):

*What does [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) do?*

According to MDN

> The `fill()` method fills **all** the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.

You can use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

In ES6, [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) can be used.

```
Array.from({length: 6}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
```

<strike>`Array.apply(null, Array(6)).map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));`</strike>

```js
var randomArr = Array.from({length: 6}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(randomArr, 0, 4); // For demo only
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

In ES5:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(6)).map(function(item, index){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
});
```

```js
var randomArr = Array.apply(null, Array(6)).map(function(item, index){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(randomArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

What is `Array.apply(null, Array(n))`? Can `new Array(n)` used here?

Both the above code create new array of six elements, each element having value as `undefined`. However, when used `new` syntax, the created array is not iterable. To make the array iterable, `Array.apply(null, Array(6))` syntax is used.

---

If you have [lodash](https://lodash.com/) included on page, it's really easy.

```
_.times(6, _.random.bind(0, 100))
        ^                        - Number of elements in array
                         ^       - Random number range min
                            ^^^  - Random number range max
```

**Note:** This answer is inspired from [Colin Toh's blog](http://colintoh.com/blog/lodash-10-javascript-utility-functions-stop-rewriting#3)_create_an_array_of_n_size_and_populate_them_with_unique_values_of_the_same_prefix)

Comment: With ES2015 you can also do: Array.from({length: 6}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9))

Comment: Thank you @NicolaBizzoca. Didn't know that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
var randoms = Array(4).fill(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
```

This line of code will create a list of 4 of the same number because `fill` takes a single value and repeats it for the length of the list.  What you want to do is run the random number generator each time:

```
var makeARandomNumber = function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
}
var randoms = Array(5).fill(0).map(makeARandomNumber);
console.log(randoms)
// => [4, 4, 3, 2, 6]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t4jtjcde/

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I'm just unsure why @Tushar used *apply()* in there. It seems that I get the same result without it but I'm cautious enough to know that there might be dragons here and there. Also, I wonder why you're using the zero argument in *fill()*. I seem to be getting the same results without it (trying both *fill(null)* and simply *fill()*). Is it a better style? Does it prevent something down the road?

Comment: re fill(0), just wanted to give it something, no real plan there.  re Tushar's use of apply(), they mention that they do that to make the array iterable.  I haven't played with it to test that behavior out, but not all objects respond to javascript's built-in looping constructs the way you'd expect because sometimes something look like an array when really it's an object with index properties. i choose to ignore these details and just use lodash for everything

Answer (score 5):

> Short and simple ES6 approach -

```
// randomly generated n = 4 length array 0 <= array[n] <= 9
var randoms = Array.from({length: 4}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
```

> Enjoy!

Comment: What exactly is {length: 4} here? A search only pulls up the String length property, `.length`, which I believe is a different construction.

Comment: If as a first parameter we provide an object contained length property the Array.from() knows that it can generate a sequence of numbers. 
Read about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

`const t =  Array.from({length: n}, mapArrowFx);

1) `const t10 =  Array.from({length: 10}, (v, k) => k); 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

2)  `const tEven =  Array.from({length: 10}, (v, k) => 2*k); 
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]`

........

3)

`let n=100;
const tRandom=  Array.from({length: n}, (v, k) => Math.floor(Math.random()*n));`

...

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure this was a correct reply, mate? Seems a bit... random.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from  [Sized array of random unique numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743588/sized-array-of-random-unique-numbers/57146249#57146249)

```js
const uniqRandomNumbers  = _.sampleSize(_.range(9), 4);
console.log(uniqRandomNumbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```