# What's the first argument of Array.apply in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

In [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966558/1525840), @Tushar suggested the syntax corresponding to the following.

```
Array.apply(null, Array(3).fill(10))
  .map(function (item, index) { 
    return item + index;
  });
```

I do understand what's going on here and I'm satisfied. However, it bugs me a bit that there's this *null* valued argument doing seemingly nothing. So I went off and started researching. According to the wisdom [on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it's a reference to *this*. Now, that gave me very little clarity and despite of putting in cucumbers, arrays, and objects into that, it didn't affect jack, as far I could tell. In fact, I'm curious why the following wouldn't be equivalent, let alone suffice.

```
Array(3).fill(10)
  .map(function (item, index) { 
    return item + index;
  });
```

Further on, I read something about Cr an IE not accepting array-like objects, which tells me even less. Also, it's a bit hard to verify the age of the article so the validity of its claim's hard to assess. I got as far as to the talk about prototype constructors and gave up, not being sure if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of `apply` is only important if you're using a function that uses `this`.

Running the following snippet should make it a little clearer:

```
var o = {value: 1};

var fn = function(a) {
    console.log(a + this.value);
}
value = "something else";

fn("an argument ");
fn.apply(o, [20]);

// the above prints:
// an argument something else
// 21
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f2zw8edd/

Answer (score 0):

`Array(number)` creates an array of the given size, however it does not populate any of its data points. Calling `map` or `fill` or pretty much anything else on it therefore won't do anything useful.

`Array(item1, item2, item...)` on the other hand creates an array with the given items as elements of the array. You can call `map`, `fill`, whatever you want on this and it will work.

So how can you use this to create an array of a given size that you can call `map` on? Exactly the way you see.

What `Array.apply(null,Array(3))` does is create an unpopulated array of size `3`, then passes those 3 undefined items as arguments to `Array`, thus resulting in
`Array(undefined,undefined,undefined)`, which gives you a `map`pable array. It's important to note that you're creating two arrays here, but the `Array(3)` is discarded after use.

So why `null`? That would be because when creating an array, there is no place where `this` is relevant. Since the context is irrelevant, you can pass literally anything you want as the context and it will run just fine, but it's easiest to understand that context doesn't matter if you pass it `null`.

Comment: I paste both code samples in my browser's console. Out, there's *[10, 11,12]* coming and I see no difference between those two. What do I miss?

Comment: Fill does indeed fill holes.