# how to make an iterable of promises programmatically js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a function that makes an iterable of promises programmatically to call them by using `promise.all` like this:

```
   const fetchRandomItems = async (numberOfItems) => 
   const myPromises = [fetchRandomItem, fetchRandomItem, fetchRandomItem] // The length of this array should be equal to numberOfItems
   promise.all(myPromises)
}
```

I dont know how to make myPromises's length equal to numberOfItems

Please and Thanks!

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, so the simplest thing i can suggest is `let mypromises = []; for (let i= 0; i < numberofitems; i++) myPromises.push(fetchRandomItem); Promise.all(myPromises)`  where `fetchRandomItem` is a promise. If that isn't what you are asking, elaborate your question ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1295584/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34966459/1048572, etc

Comment: Thaanks, I didnt realize that was a simple thing, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build an array as if promises were any other object.

```js
const fetchRandomItems = numberOfItems => {
    const myPromises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        myPromises.push(fetchRandomItem());
    }
    return Promise.all(myPromises);
}
```

or

```js
const fetchRandomItems = numberOfItems => 
    Promise.all([...Array(numberOfItems)].map(() => fetchRandomItem()))
```

Comment: thanks man, you really helped me a lot :D

Comment: A question, in the 1st line of the for loop, when `myPromises.push(fetchRandomItem())` is runned, the `fetchRandomItem()` is made?

Comment: @sankiago I'm not sure I understand your question, but this code assumes that fetchRandomItem() is an async function. Async functions return promises.