# Object doesn't support property or method 'fill'

Tags: javascript

I cannot find same problem online. IE 11 gives error "Object doesn't support property or method `fill`".

```
var arr = new Array(5);
arr.fill(false);
```

Is there any convenient way to to fill an array instead of using a `for` loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the [trivial polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill) and continue using `.fill(…)`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Don't agonize about whether or not your favorite method is available - just provide a polyfill in case it isn't.

Answer (score 22):

I face the same issue, not to add anything.

Just open polyfills.ts file and un-comment following lines:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Every thing will start working.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).apply for getting an array with the wanted length and then map the value to it.

```js
var a = Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(function () { return false; });
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Notice that this is quite slow for large arrays, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have face same issue and need to uncomment following lines in polyfill.ts file as follows:

> Polyfill.ts file path: angular-App=> src=> polyfill.ts

Open this file and uncomment following lines

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Now it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

fill(); Does not support in IE. It is introduced in EDGE though. I guess foreach is the convenient way to do the task. Will update if find more. You can read the following :

- [Array Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [efficient way to fill 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

Add below script to download pollyfill from CDN to your index file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=default,Array.prototype.includes"></script>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = Array.from(Array(10), () => 'none')
console.log(arr)
// ['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']
```