# JavaScript ArrayBuffer slice apparently broken in Safari 9.1.2

Tags: javascript, safari

A basic JavaScript function seems to be broken in Safari 9.1.2 (10601.7.7).  Perhaps I am just doing something wrong?  Looking for advice on how to work past this...

The function in question is [ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice)

Here's a usage example that works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
var bufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
console.log(bufferView.slice(0,8)); // TypeError: bufferView.slice is not a function
```

Comment: In what sense does it not work? Is there an error? Does something weird happen?

Comment: What do you mean it's "broken?" Are you getting an error? Is it giving you the wrong selection?

Comment: @Pointy, when I run the code, Safari's web inspector tells me: TypeError: bufferView.slice is not a function. (In 'bufferView.slice(0,8)', 'bufferView.slice' is undefined)

Comment: You're calling `.slice()` on the Uint8Array object, *not* on the ArrayBuffer, and [`.slice()` is not supported on typed arrays in Safari and Internet Explorer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice)

Comment: Ah hah.  Thanks for the explanation.  How would you recommend dealing with this?  Would it be bad to try adding my own .slice() function to the Uint8Array object?

Comment: In case it helps anyone else who encounters this kind of issue, I got my code to work by defining my own .slice() function as follows: `if(!Uint8Array.prototype.slice){
 Uint8Array.prototype.slice = function(a,b){
  var Uint8ArraySlice = new Uint8Array(this.buffer.slice(a,b));
  return Uint8ArraySlice;
 }
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just writing this out as an answer, all the relevant facts were in comments already (thus community wiki).

You're calling `.slice()` on the `Uint8Array` object, not on the `ArrayBuffer`, and [`.slice()` is not supported on typed arrays in Safari and Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice).

Instead, you can use `bufferView.buffer.slice()`, or this helper method written by Patch:

```
if(!Uint8Array.prototype.slice)
{
    Uint8Array.prototype.slice = function(a,b){
        var Uint8ArraySlice = new Uint8Array(this.buffer.slice(a,b));
        return Uint8ArraySlice;
    }
}
```