# init Array with 5 zero elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, lambda

Hello I want to init Array with 5 zero elements in JS. Without classic `initiation var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I try some variant:

```
var arr = new Array(5).map(() => 0);
var arr = new Array(5).map(function () {return 0;});
var arr = Array(5).map(function () {return 0;});
```

but this examples are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `.fill`:

```js
const arr = new Array(5).fill(0);
console.log(arr);
```

or `Array.from`, which has a built-in map function you can pass as a second parameter:

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => 0);
console.log(arr);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

Using `Array.from` as above assigns *undefined* values to each element of the array, whereas `new Array` does not, which is why you can `map` after `Array.from` but not after invoking the Array constructor.

Comment: please do not answer duplicates.

Comment: The first solution is already covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326623/5894241 And the second one is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411148/5894241

Answer (score 0):

You need use method fill for array's in initialization.

example:

```
var arr = new Array(5).fill(0);
```

Comment: please do not answer duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

May a for loop help you?

```
For(i=0; i<N; i++){
    array[i]=value;
}
```

For a 5 length array of 0 it becomes

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    array[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: please do not answer duplicates.

Comment: When I started writing there was no answer. It is not simple to write code on smartphone app