# create an array of zeroes of specified length javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking for the JS equivalent of

[0]*n for creating an array(lists in python) of n length. How do I do that using the Javascript?

Comment: `Array(n).fill(0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//12 is an axample, the length of the array
let arr = new Array(12).fill(0);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Hey is there something I can do to make it change the 0 into a float? fill seems to be truncating