# How to create { 0: false, 1: false, 2: false, ..., 99: false } the shortest way in JavaScript (preferably using Lodash?)

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Question is in the title. I want to make an object that has all keys from  0 to 99 and all values should be `false`.

I can figure out how to do this in JavaScript ES6 in a couple lines, but wondering if somebody can think of a one-line solution? I've tried with different `lodash` methods such as `keyBy`, `map`, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Why not just use an array? An object with keys as numbers is really all an array is. Then it's [`new Array(99).fill(false)`](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/4-ways-to-populate-an-array-in-javascript-836952aea79f).

Comment: The keys in `{ 0: false, 1: false }` are strings. You should use an array `[false, false]` if you want numbers.

Comment: Because I'm mapping which rows of a 100-row table are selected in React, so when they get selected I set the ones with the right index to `true`. It's stored in a state, and I find that adding/removing elements from arrays to be a bit messy in JS. It's fine if the keys are strings, I'm just trying to change the value to `true` of the particular rows that are selected, which is easy to understand with an object

Comment: @jabaa that's fine if they are strings

Comment: You could not add those keys from 0 to 99, and when calling the object you could just compare if exist; ```obj.0 ? true : false```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one-liner is:

```js
Object.assign({}, new Array(100).fill(false));
```

Where we

- [Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array) an array: `new Array(length)`
- [Fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it with `false`: `fill(false)`
- [Convert to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object): `Object.assign({}, ...);`

---

```js
const obj = Object.assign({}, new Array(100).fill(false));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple like this :

```js
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  obj[i] = false;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just based on my comment I think you should use an array. Just pick up the `rowIndex`, copy the existing array, update the value at the index, and then update the state.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState(new Array(5).fill(false));

  function handleClick(e) {
    const index = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
    const newArray = [...data];
    newArray[index] = !newArray[index];
    setData(newArray);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <table onClick={handleClick}>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Bob</td><td>25</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Karen</td><td>26</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Dave</td><td>27</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Jo</td><td>35</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Steve</td><td>75</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
tr { background-color: #efefef; }
tr:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #bfbfbf; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Because the OP said they were using React. Read the comments. All the values are `false` initially but they change when the rows get clicked.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see those comments. Understand now.