# how can I make div tags as much as number in state(react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing with React.js and below is a simplified version of my component. As you can see, when I click the button state(number) would get a number. And here is what I want, make div tags as much as a number in state(number) in the form tag(which its class name is 'b').

Could you tell me how to make this possible? Thanks for reading. Your help will be appreciated.

```
//state
const[number,setNumber] = useState('')

//function
const appendChilddiv =(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault()
 setNumber('')
}
<div>
<form className="a" onSubmit={appendChilddiv}>
 
 <input
 value={number}
 onChange={(e)=>setNumber(e.target.value)}
 type="number"/>
 <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>

<div>
<form className="b">

</form>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `make div tags as much as a number` : do you want the number of divs to be equal to what you type in input, or the div's text to be same as the input's value?

Comment: @ShivamJha first One, sorry for my bad English :/

Comment: No worries, Do you want the `divs` to appear after submit, or as user types in the input ?

Comment: Thank all of you!! I solved the problem, all your answers were huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-shaw-bowis?file=/src/App.js) which includes the following code, previously you were storing the value as a string, it'd be best to store it as number so you can use that to map out, which I do via the Array() constructor (this creates an array of a fixed length, in this case the size of the `divCount` state - when we update the state by changing the input value this creates a re-render and thats why the mapping is updated with the new value)

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  //state
  const [divCount, setDivCount] = React.useState(0);
  //function
  const appendChilddiv = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Submit your form info etc.
    setDivCount(0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="a" onSubmit={appendChilddiv}>
        <input
          value={divCount}
          onChange={(e) => setDivCount(Number(e.target.value))}
          type="number"
        />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>

      <div>
        <form className="b">
          {Array(divCount)
            .fill(0)
            .map((x, idx) => (
              <div key={idx}>Div: {idx + 1}</div>
            ))}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following.

First thing it does is creates a new array of some length `number`.

Next, it fills that array with undefined, because creating new arrays like this doesn't really create an array of that length.

Lastly, we map over this array, we use the index as our key.
We return an empty div for each item in the array.

Note, using an index as a key isn't the best idea. In general it should be something as unique as possible. If you have data you can use that is unique, then you should use that as a key.

```
return new Array(number).fill(undefined).map((_, key) => <div key={key}></div>);
```

Comment: @double-beep, its not. If I recall correctly while I typed my answer a few others did also.

Edit: Actually I think I wrote mine before the one you cited.

Comment: That's a better answer, now that an explanation has been added.

Answer (score 2):

You can map over an array whose length is same as that entered in `input` & create `divs` (if number entered is valid):

```
{!isNaN(number) &&
              parseInt(number, 10) > 0 &&
              Array(parseInt(number, 10))
                .fill(0)
                .map((_, idx) => <div key={idx}>Hey!</div>)
}
```

1. [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) checks is number is valid
2. [`parseInt(number, 10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) converts string into number,
3. [`Array(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) creates a new array with `n` elements (all empty) (try console logging `Array(5)`) - so you need to fill it
4. [`.fill(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array) fill the array (make each element `n`)
5. and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is [used to render different elements from existing things](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

So, in this way, you can achieve the mentioned result.

Here's a [link to working Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-framework-k3bt2?file=/src/App.js:473-661) for your reference

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it without 'Submit' button. See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-gagarin-l0r55?file=/src/App.js) link and the code snippet below:

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [divTags, setDivTags] = useState([])
  const appendChilddiv = (e) => {
    const numberAsString = e.target.value;
    let numberDivTags;
    if (numberAsString.length === 0) {
      numberDivTags = 0
    } else {
      numberDivTags = parseInt(numberAsString, 10)
    }
    setDivTags([...Array(numberDivTags)])
    console.log(divTags)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <form className="a">
        <input type="number" onChange={appendChilddiv}/>
      </form>
      <form className="b">
        {divTags.map((e, i) => {
          return <p key={i}>Div number {i}</p>
        })}
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```