# How to create an array with a set amount of elements inside all set to 0? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

If I want to create an array containing a piece of data for every minute of the year (525,600 elements for 365 day year) or (524,160 elements for 364 day year) is there a way to create an array with a set amount of elements inside all set to a value of 0?

```
const minutesOfTheYear = [];
minutesOfTheYear[0] = 0;
minutesOfTheYear[1] = 0;
minutesOfTheYear[2] = 0;
/* ... */
minutesOfTheYear[525,599] = 0;
```

I think I could use a for loop, setting the amount of loops to 525,600 and the index of the array amended to add by 1 each time, but what is the proper way to declare the new values within a for loop? Would this work?

```
for (let i = 0; i< 525599; i++) {
 minutesOfTheYear[i] = 0;
}
```

Or is there a line of code that just declares the size of the array and auto populates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array/53029824

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const result = Array.from({ length: 524160 }, () => 0);

console.log(result);
```

The second argument is a map function - it is run once for each item in the array, and it must return the value for that item. In this example, it's simply returning `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array(100).fill(0)  // length is 100
```